# EF 5.0: "No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo `long?` a long", Ya existe una conversión explicita (Compruebe si falta una conversión)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, entity-framework, linq

estoy trabajando con EntityFramework 5.0 y MVC (Database First) y estoy teniendo este problema en mi controlador, ya que al querer utilizar la propiedad idStencil me aparece este error

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo `long?` a long", Ya
> existe una conversión explicita (Compruebe si falta una conversión)

en la base de datos este campo se encuentra como (BIGINT) y al crear el proyecto EF me creo la propiedad como tipo long y en mi modelo al ponerla ya sea long,Int64 o int me sigue apareciendo el error. Muchas gracias cualquier ayuda es bienvenida! :D
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Oscar podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles y marcar como aceptada la que más te haya ayudado, gracias

Comment: Considera realizar el [tour] y mirarte la sección de la ayuda de [ask] para aprender a realizar preguntas sin tener que pegar imágenes de código, ni en las preguntas ni en las respuestas, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo el problema no es que sea long a int64, el problema es que uno es null y el otro no, no puedes asignar null a un not null, y es lo que te esta diciendo, en tu modelo debe de estar idStencil como no requerido.

solo tienes que declarar tu idStencil en tu modelo como nulleable

```
pubic Nullable<Int64> idStencil {get;set;}
```

o validar en tu selector si es nullo poner un valor

```
idStencil = RSR.idStencil ?? 0;
```

Comment: Eso pasa cuando en tu definicion de la tabla en tu DB esta como no requerido. Asi que la otra seria ponerlo como requerido y volver a generar ese modelo en tu EF

Answer (score 0):

Un tipo de datos **long?**, es lo mismo que el tipo de datos **long**, pero admite el valor **null**, es decir, es lo que se conoce como un **tipo de datos nulleable**.

Para obtener el valor de un **nulleable** debes hacer:

```
long x = y.Value;
```

De esta forma guardamos en la **variable x** el valor numérico del **nulleable** guardado en la **variable y**.

Para saber si un tipo **nulleable** tiene asociado un valor puedes usar la **propiedad HasValue**, es decir:

```
if (y.HasValue)
{
   x = y.Value;
}
```

Si el **nulleable y** tiene asociado un valor entonces se lo asignamos a la **variable x**.

Comment: En realidad es como un tipo envolvente o un contenedor.